# adb and platform-tools not working anymore on Mac Lion

Tags: applications, adb, macos

Ok, I had that eclipse + SDK + all projects working fine on my Mac (Osx Lion). After updating the SDK recently, everything stopped working. It seems that some very smart guy there forgot to allow adtand platform-tools to Mac Osx Lion (possibly because he has a newer version and he didn't care too much that other people don't. So, now I am stuck because I can't find a way to downgrade it back to where I was before the update. It seems there's no page from where I can download just the platform-tools in the version I had before. Any hint? Does anyone have a previous version of that folder?

Answer (score 1):

Hint, Google repository. Ah here you go a better example from the [past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555337/how-to-downgrade-my-sdk-version)

1. Find your Sdk folder then locate both tools and platform-tools subfolders.
2. Check the [Google repository](https://android.googlesource.com)  find what version you want to downgrade to and download the .ZIP for both.
3. Unpack the the .ZIP's you just downloaded move the Tools subfolder over to your Android Sdk folder. Then move and extract the Platform-tools subfolder to your Android Sdk folder.

Now you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this version of platform-tools is working on MacOS 10.7.5 with a device running Android 7.1.1.

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r20-macosx.zip